# Creating relations between classes in web ontology language(owl)

Tags: rdf, taxonomy, ontology, owl, rdfs

I need to define relations between classes in my ontology in OWL syntax.
what should i do?

Comment: Your code didn't show up, I fixed the formatting. The easiest way to include code snippets on StackOverflow is to indent every code line by four spaces.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that there are two XML syntaxes (in addition to several other non-XML syntaxes) that you can use to write OWL. Your snippet is in RDF/XML syntax. The other syntax is OWL/XML. The [OWL Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/) has examples of both syntaxes.

Your snippet says:

- The URI `<#net>` identifies a class.
- This class has the label “network” (a string).
- This class is in a “hasPart” relationship with something that is identified by the URI `<#Node>`.

The first two things make sense, but the last one doesn't really. I guess what you really want to say is:

- The URI `<#Node>` also identifies a class.
- The URI `<#hasPart>` identifies a property that connects individuals of two classes (an `owl:ObjectProperty`).
- The subjects of the hasPart property are networks (in other words, the domain of hasPart is `#net`).
- The objects of the hasPart property are nodes (in other words, the range of hasPart is `#node`).

Looking at the examples in the OWL Primer should give you a decent idea how to write these things down. But also note that writing the RDF/XML syntax by hand is tedious and error-prone. You probably want to use an OWL editor like TopBraid Composer, or a programming library like OWL-API, to create your OWL files. If you really want to write them by hand, I recommend using Turtle syntax (again, the Primer has examples), because it's much more readable, and gives you a head start towards learning SPARQL, the query language for OWL and RDF.

Comment: I want to develop an ontology in owl , so that all of the nodes may contains relations with others that can be bidirectional.As i understood from protege we can just define relationship between
individuals of different classes.What
i need is defining relation between classes themselves
in any level like is a relation which is the default in hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with cygri that relating `#net` to `#Node` like this does not seem to make sense, and probably you'd like that all instances of `#net` have a part or some parts that are instances of `#Node`. To do this, you can write:

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Node"/>
<owl:Class rdf:ID="net">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasPart"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Node"/>
        </owl/Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

You may still want to define properties that connect two classes directly. For instance:

```
<#Node>  <#isSimilarTo>  <#Vertice> .
```

To do this in OWL, you can define an `owl:AnnotationProperty`:

```
<owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="isSimilarTo"/>
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Node">
    <isSimilarTo rdf:resource="#Vertice"/>
</owl:Class>
```

Or you can use "punning", that is, use a class as an instance, e.g.:

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="isSimilarTo"/>
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Node">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
    <isSimilarTo>
        <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Vertice"/>
    </isSimilarTo>
</owl:Class>
```

Note that in OWL DL, all instances must be explicitly typed. Here, `#Node`  is declared as both a class and an instance of `owl:Thing`. This does not mean that `owl:Thing` can contain classes, but it means that `#Node` refer to two distinct things: a class and an instance. In OWL DL, the context in which an IRI appear always makes it clear what the term refers to.